# Selecting multiple values from DropDownList in CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Cloudformation expert,

Is it possible to be able to select multiple values from a dropdownlist in Cloudformation Template?

I tried something like this but it didn't work

```
  pTypeOfAccountNeeded:
    Default: "Tools, Sandbox, Dev, Test (QA), Preprod, Prod"
    AllowedValues: 
      - "Tools"
      - "Sandbox"
      - "Dev"
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunate, this is **not possible**.

If you want to have few such values provided by users, you have to define your parameter as follows (an example):

```
  pTypeOfAccountNeeded:
    Default: "Tools,Dev"
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    AllowedValues: 
      - "Tools,Sandbox"
      - "Sandbox"
      - "Tools,Dev"
```